# Angular2 Service Subject Subscription, Save Last Value

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-observables

I have sample service subject:

```
private categoryFilterTypeSource = new ReplaySubject<number>();

    categoryFilterType$ = this.categoryFilterTypeSource.asObservable();

    changeFilterType(newValue: number) {
        this.categoryFilterTypeSource.next(newValue);
    }
```

when i subscribe on this subject, i want to get last sent value for new subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

Then create an array and push the last value to the array.  Pop it when you need it.